# Inset box shadow behind h2's background image/color, need it above

Tags: html, background, css

As the title suggests I'm having an issue with an inset box shadow going underneath my H2 elements background, I need it to be above the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/9QYT4/

I've set the background image up to allow easy editing of the colors depending on pages of the site visited, any help on how to make the shadow appear above the h2 is appreciated, thanks!

Also, would it be possible to do something like this with a png gradient as well? That would be  a better solution as I'm trying to only get the shadow on the right (but it's showing on the top and bottom as well)

SASS

```
#region-postscript-second {
width:300px;
background:#fff;
margin: 20px;
box-shadow: inset -6px 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
h2 {
    background: url('http://vt.lexcorp.ca/sites/all/themes/vermont/img/middle-heading-bg.png') center center no-repeat #8CCC1B;
    font-size:20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#646567;
    text-align:center;
}}
```

View the HTML on the JSfiddle, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created pseudo after element that contains your shadow: http://jsfiddle.net/jPUX3/

```
#region-postscript-second:after{
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%; width: 14px;
    box-shadow: inset -14px 0 8px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

and to #region-postscript-second I added:

```
position: relative;
```

Here at the end is something about one side box-shadows - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/